# WCF Endpoint address problems

Tags: wcf, web-services

I created a WCF web service and created a new site in IIS (7).  I created a new port (8002) for http requests.  I can browse to the site and get the typical "You do not have permission to view this directory ..." so I know the site is working.  However, I set my endpoint address to "http://1.1.1.1:8002" in my web.config (where 1.1.1.1 is replaced with my actual real IP address).  when I browse to the service with http://1.1.1.1:8002/service.svc I get page cannot be found error.  There is a service.svc in the root folder of the site.  What is wrong with the setup?

Here is the web.config file if helpful (again, the 1.1.1.1 is replaced with my real IP address):

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicBinding">
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService.ServiceBehavior" name="WcfService.Service">
            <endpoint address="http://1.1.1.1:8002" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding" contract="WcfService.IService">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService.ServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: What's is the name of the site's folder? Have you tried hitting http://1.1.1.1:8002/<root name>/service.svc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot control the address of your service in configuration file when hosting in IIS. You can control only relative address of the endpoint - it is relative to .svc file.

So if you host the service in the site http://YourIP:8002 its address is http://YourIP:8002/Service.svc and the address element in the endpoint is relative to this address. But I expect you don't host the service directly in the site. You have some application in the site and the name of the application is part of the URL: http://YourIP:8002/YourApplicationName/Service.svc Actually every folder used to nest the service is part of the URL.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of adding /Service.svc and the same results.  The browser says the page cannot be found.  The Service.svc is inside the root directory of the site and not a subfolder.  Ihave even enabled browsing of the site and can see the Service.svc.  When I click on it, the browser says the webpage cannot be found.

Comment: That worked.  Now the question is why is the address need to be blank?  I always see an address listed.  Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: I tried to explain it in my answer - when hosting in IIS the base address is always fixed by IIS itself. The address in endpoint is only relative part (suffix) added to that fixed part.